# Acumatica's implementation of LastModifiedDateTime / Filtering

Tags: rest, filtering, acumatica

Implementation:  22.200.001
Interface:       Rest API
Request:         GET
Params:          $filter
Value:           LastModifiedDateTime gt "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000"
EndPoints:       All

Problem - When requesting any records greater than LastModifiedDateTime the system returns records that are within the span of the date (e.g. 0:00 hrs to 23:59.999") requested instead of any records that are ACTUALLY greater than the datetime requested.

Question - Is this by design or is this a bug?  If by design, why store the time?  Why report time down to milliseconds?

Programming Issue - Causes undo update SQL calls for records that do not need to be updated.  Yes, one could query prior to updating but that defeats the purpose of the filter.

Any insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

No programming issue but rather an implementation question.

Comment: Do you have access to Acumatica support cases? If so opening a case would be the best bet to understand underlying behavior of framework.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a date as a filter, you need to use datetimeoffset:

```
$filter=LastModifiedDateTime gt datetimeoffset'2023-03-17T16:00:00.000-05:00'
```

You can find an example in I310 training course.